# Printing out datetime in a specific format in Java?

Tags: java

I want to print out datetime in java in a specific format. I have this C# code which prints out the datetime in this format.

```
DateTime value = new DateTime(2010, 1, 18);
Console.WriteLine(value);
Console.WriteLine(value == DateTime.Today);
```

The result is - 1/18/2010 12:00:00 AM

Now, I want to write a java code that prints out the datetime in the same format. I used the joda.time library. This is what I tried so far.

```
DateTime today = new DateTime();
System.out.println(today.toString(“yyyy-MMM-dd”));
```

How can I pass the year,month and day as the constructor in the DateTime in java and print out in the above format.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Approach 1: Using [java.time.LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). (**Strongly Preferred**)

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dtf.format(now)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

Approach 2: Using [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

Approach 3: Using [java.util.Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

Comment: I suggest you reverse these, so that the `java.time` answer is first, as it's *strongly* preferred (IMO) over the other two.

Comment: @Wasi Ahmad: - Thanks you very much.

Comment: And note that `java.time` package only exists since JDK 8, so `java.util.Date` is the way to go in Java < 8. @JonSkeet any preference between `Date` and `Calendar`?

Comment: @Matthieu: No, `java.util.Date` isn't the only way to go - there's also Joda Time, which is the way I would do any date/time work in pre-Java8. As for whether to use `Date` or `Calendar` - they represent different things, so use whichever is most suitable for your use case.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you. As for `java.util.Date`, I meant "without external library". I think everybody is using Joda Time when it's needed :)

Comment: @Matthieu: I think a great number of people *aren't* using Joda Time, but really should be, either due to lack of awareness or an irrational fear of introducing an external library. (There are times when the fear is rational, certainly - but a lot of the fears *aren't* in those contexts.)

Answer (score 5):

If you need date in 24 hour system then use this approach

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date custDate = new Date();
System.out.println(sdf.format(custDate));
```

Please note in 24 hour system there is no need to show AM/PM.

If you want date in 12 hour system then use below approach

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date custDate = new Date();
System.out.println(sdf.format(custDate));
```

"a" in the date format will help to show AM/PM.

Please import below classes for above code to work

> java.text.SimpleDateFormat
>
> java.util.Date

Answer (score 4):

```
LocalDate.of(2010, 1, 18).atStartOfDay().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"))
```

or

```
LocalDate.of(2010, 1, 18).atTime(12, 0, 0).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"));
```

if you want to add the time too

Answer (score -1):

Please try to this one

```
public void Method(Datetime time)
{
    
    time.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please read the question carefully. OP's question *Printing out datetime in a specific format in Java?* asks for a solution in Java, and not C#. Your code may work in C# but not in Java; please revise your answer or consider removing it as it currently doesn't answer OP's question.